# C# combine two different sets of lists for iteration

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have lists of two Shapes - Rectangles and Circles.
They both share 3 common properties - ID , Type and Bounds

Circles have 2 extra properties - Range and Center

How can i join lists of each type into a single list so i can iterate over them so i don't have to type two foreach cycles

Could this be donne in a better way than combining the lists ?

```
public interface IRectangle
{
    string Id { get; set; }
    GeoLocationTypes Type { get; set; }
    Bounds Bounds { get; set; }
}

public class Rectangle : IRectangle
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public GeoLocationTypes Type { get; set; }

    public Bounds Bounds { get; set; }
}


public interface ICircle
{
    string Id { get; set; }
    GeoLocationTypes Type { get; set; }
    Bounds Bounds { get; set; }
    float Radius { get; set; }
    Coordinates Center { get; set; }
}

public class Circle : ICircle
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public GeoLocationTypes Type { get; set; }


    public Bounds Bounds { get; set; }

    public float Radius { get; set; }

    public Coordinates Center { get; set; }
}

public class Bounds
{
    public Coordinates NE { get; set; }

    public Coordinates SW { get; set; }
}

public class Coordinates
{
    public float Lat { get; set; }

    public float Lng { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend first having Circle and Rectangle be convertible to an `IShape` (they derive from that interface).  As you have it now, Circle and Rectangles share no commonality.

Comment: Define "better".  More efficient?  Easier to maintain/read? Is there a reason they're in separate lists to begin with? You could have your different shapes descent from a more abstract object type and use a list of <your abstract type> but then you'd have to cast the object to the correct specific subclass when iterating that more generic list, if you needed to reference their specific properties. List<animals> ... contains giraffes, hyenas, zebras, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make both `IRectangle` and `ICircle` inherit from a shared type - say `IShape`.

A `List<IShape>` will then be able to take any `IRectangle` and `ICircle` types and their inheriting types.

Since both `IRectangle` and `ICircle` share a number of properties, you can do this:

```
public interface IShape
{
    string Id { get; set; }
    GeoLocationTypes Type { get; set; }
    Bounds Bounds { get; set; }
}

public interface ICircle : IShape
{
    float Radius { get; set; }
    Coordinates Center { get; set; }
}

public interface IRectangle : IShape
{
}
```

Comment: @JonEgerton - Yes, though the question and the OOP inheritance literature almost guarantee this response ;)

Comment: Q: what happens when i go to irerate the lists is i see only the properties of IShape , how do i access the ones of IRectangle when i hit one durring iteration?

Comment: @Aviatrix - Well, the point is that you are only supposed to use the properties of `IShape` and that's the guarantee of what types are in the list. You _can_ cast or use the [`as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) operator to convert to an `IRectangle`, but then why use `List<IShape>` at all?

Answer (score 5):

Make an interface `IShape` that contains the common properties, then implement that as well as ICircle and IRectangle. (You could also use a base class that has the properties).

You should them be able to join list of Circles and Rectangles to get a list of IShapes.

Answer (score 3):

You could further add an interface

```
public interface IShape
{
    string Id;
    GeoLocationTypes Type;
    Bounds Bounds;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make them each use an IShape interface, or you could iterate over Objects and cast.

```
public interface IShape
{
    string Id { get; set; }
    GeoLocationTypes Type { get; set; }
    Bounds Bounds { get; set; }
}

public interface IRectangle : IShape { }

public class Rectangle : IRectangle
{
    // No change
}


public interface ICircle : IShape
{
    float Radius { get; set; }
    Coordinates Center { get; set; }
}

public class Circle : ICircle
{
    // No change
}

public class Bounds
{
    // No change
}

public class Coordinates
{
    // No change
}
```

There is also the [Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698%28VS.100%29.aspx) function that will allow  you to enumerate over all of them.

An example:

```
var numbers= new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var words = new [] { "one", "two", "three" };

var numbersAndWords = numbers.Zip(words, (n, w) => new { Number = n, Word = w });
foreach(var nw in numbersAndWords)
{
    Console.WriteLine(nw.Number + nw.Word);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
var merged = Rectagles.Select(r => new { 
        r.Id, 
        r.Type, 
        r.Bounds,
        Radius = float.NaN,
        Centre = default(Coordinates) })
    .Concat(Circles.Select(c => new {
        c.Id, 
        c.Type, 
        c.Bounds,
        c.Radius,
        c.Centre }));
```

it gives a list of enumerable of an anonymous type that exposes the required information.

---

**EDIT**

To my amazement this actually seems to compile. So there is a solution that works without defining a common interface. However for anything but the quick and dirty I would consider polymorphic over anonymous.